# What should I do if my adapter isn't capable of packet injection?

Tags: wifi, wps

I tried the aireplay test but it said "No Answers" instead of "Injection is working". I also get error of  List of possible errors (which also includes packet injection problem) when trying to associate with aireplay. But my adapter is in monitor mode.

```
aireplay-ng --test wlan1mon
```

gives

```
Trying broadcast probe requests...
No Answers...
Found 0 APs
```

My chipset is a Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070

I'm kind of a beginner in this so go a little easy on me. Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED:**

The test result says "No Answers..." and "Found 0 APs". There was no AP nearby that can give answer to ensure that your adapter actually supports packet injection, so of course there's no answer from any AP.

Make sure you are close enough to the AP (any WiFi hotspot). If that didn't work, Go to aircrack's official site to check whether your adapter is capable or not.

Comment: buy a new adapter that supports packet injection!

Comment: Take a look at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135837/strange-behavior-when-injection-wifi-packets-with-aireplay-ng/135841#135841
It is not exactly the same, but looks related

Comment: No, that's not the issue. tried it. see edited question for the error

Comment: Are you close enough to the AP, have you tried another card, maybe it's an OS problem. What is your OS version?

Comment: many blogs referred to it as an OS problem, you need to install kernel headers and other required files, try to use another OS with another version.

Comment: OMFG IT WORKED. INJECTION IS WORKING. I used my phone's hotspot and it worked. I guess the issue was that I was far from the AP. thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the [aircrack](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatible_cards) article about supported cards? Start there to begin with. They even have a tool to test if your cards supports monitor/injection mode. If the hardware doesn't support modes other than station infrastructure mode, you're out of luck. If it does, then make sure you have the correct drivers supporting this feature. At last you OS should have the tools to inject/monitor, but this is not the problem, most of the time.

From what I have found (just by searching, I haven't actually confirmed anything) is your card doesn't support injection or monitor mode.

Comment: Thanks, but actually the problem this whole time was I wasn't close enough to the AP. see my comment above

Comment: @BenJunior Next time, RTFM and there would have been no need to post this question.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue but I realized my device was under monitor mode and needed to be under managed mode, here are the steps for both:

Setting up the card in monitor mode

```
#Set interface down
sudo ip link set wlan0 down
#Set monitor mode
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
#Set interface up
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
Verifying monitor mode
sudo iwconfig
```

---

Testing card by sniffing nearby networks

```
sudo airodump-ng wlan0
```

---

Changing the adapter back to manage mode

```
#Set interface down
sudo ip link set wlan0 down
#Set monitor mode
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed
#Set interface up
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
#Try again... 
sudo aireplay-ng --test wlan0
```